# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
I = imread('15943.jpg');

Ib=imread('BG.png');

I1=rgb2gray(I);
Ib1=rgb2gray(Ib);
Ib2= imresize(Ib1,size(I1));

Id=imsubtract(Ib2,I1);
Id=Id;
Id=bwareaopen(Id,500,8);
Id=imfill(Id,'holes');
Id=uint8(Id);
[r c]=size(Id);
for i=1:r
    for j=1:c
        if Id(i,j)==255
            Id(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end

im(:,:,1)=I(:,:,1).*Id; % error
im(:,:,2)=I(:,:,2).*Id;
im(:,:,3)=I(:,:,3).*Id;
```

I know that this error arises when there is a difference in dimension. But I don't understand why here is issue is raised.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `I` and the dimensions of `Id`?

Comment: @beaker I have added the code above which makes sure that their dimensions are equal. I want this code to be generic as I have 500 images

Comment: Okay, but a quick check of the dimension of the images that are actually giving you the problem would give a big clue as to where the error is.

Comment: LIke @beaker said, please provide `size(I)` and `size(Ib)` if possible.

Comment: Should I do it like this then ? im(:,1)=I(:,1).*Id;

Comment: Please show the results of the commands @edwinksl gave, `size(I)` and `size(Id)`, immediately prior to the line that gives the error.

Comment: size of Id= 537   402 and size of I=   537   402     3

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. Unless `im` has previously been declared, the sizes should match.

Comment: No it hasn't been declared before.

Comment: `im` was probably still in your workspace.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thanks @beaker (y)

Comment: Recommended is that you always write code as functions. At most there should be one file which is not a function in a project. That is the main file from where you run the main function. This one is for the user to provide configurations and may be a script in case the save would brake for some reason and the program is run over night.